# Debugging a Pig UDF by aggregating warnings

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig

I'm trying to use the warn() method in my Pig UDF like this:

```
public class MyUDF extends EvalFunc<Tuple> {

    public Tuple exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {

        boolean condition = true;         
        while(condition) {
            // Some business logic
            warn("There was a problem", PigWarning.UDF_WARNING_1);
        }
    }

}
```

When I run my pig script using this UDF locally, I never see these warnings aggregate at the end of the job.

How can I configure pig to see the aggregated warning?

Comment: What *do* you see at the end of the job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out that in local mode, you'll never see aggregated warnings. You need to be in MapReduce mode to see them!